# angularjs : How to resolve cross domain issue in chrome and firefox which is working perfectly in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am facing cross domain issue in chrome and firefox which works fine in IE. I had tried `$http.jsonp()` as well but still facing the same issue.

**JS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,$compile){
var serverName = "home.mcafee.com/";
var apiRequest = "http://infraapi.int.mcafee.com/api/DBData/";

$scope.ajaxCall = function(){
    $http.get(apiRequest+serverName)
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.Detail = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: So basically your problem is in chrome and firefox and works perfectly fine in IE? and if so please elaborate the problem. which part is not working and on what action?

Comment: $http.get() request works fine in IE but not in chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you trying these two options:

1. Insert this command in your terminal:
   --disable-web-security
2. Install this extension to chrome: 
   Allow-Control-Allow-Origin * 
   Link => https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

By default browsers don't allow cross origin requests. this security feature is implemented in almost all browsers. But, there still some old browsers which are do not provide this security. In this case IE.

However you can disable web security at your own risk. but, this is not permanent solution, because we cannot ask every user to disable it.

The solution is to set access-control-allow-origin response headers server side. But, if your ajax end point is a third party you may ask them to add these headers. if not you must not use their service, because their intention to implement the application is not be used outside.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer use local webserver (gulp webserver or webpack) rather then adjust browser by disabling web-security or something else